# Why are all my punctuation characters displaying at the beginning of my texts in HTML?

Tags: html, css

When I render my HTML I have all the punctuation at the beginning.
For example:

```html
<p>What is going on ?</p>
```

would display as "?What is going on". What can cause this?

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was the CSS `direction` property that was set to `rtl` (right to left). I just removed it and now everything displays normally.